# i have repeater with check boxes i wants to delete records when one or more check boxes are checked on button click event

Tags: asp.net

i tried but its not working 
codes are as follows

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete"))
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater2.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBoxID");

            if (chk.Checked)
            {

               SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.64;Initial Catalog=arvind;User ID=sa;password=platinum50");
               cn1.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete * from Employee_Login " ,cn1 ); 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error is microsoft run time error-form name="Form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="Form1" onsubmit="Check(this)" at this line and saying object is expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your SQL command the ID of the item you want to delete (you can store this in the `CommandArgument` property) otherwise it won't know which row to delete from the `Employee_Login` table.

Also, you also need to `Execute` your command - at the moment all you are doing is defining it.

And after you have executed your command, you need to rebind the repeater.

HTH.

EDIT:

PS. Take a look at this if you're still having problems: http://bit.ly/fnLFRx